# LSTM not learning, no MSE

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Hi I am having trouble with finding the correct inputshape for my LTSM model. I have been trying to find a shape that fits but have trouble understanding what is required.

I think the problem is in the ytest and ytrain shape. Why is it not the same shape as xtrain and xtest?

```
xtrain (80304, 37)
xtest (39538, 37)
ytrain (80304,)
ytest (39538,)
Epoch 1/3
2510/2510 [==============================] - 34s 13ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/3
2510/2510 [==============================] - 32s 13ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/3
2510/2510 [==============================] - 33s 13ms/step - loss: nan
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_10 (LSTM)               (None, 4)                 96        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 5         
=================================================================
Total params: 101
Trainable params: 101
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model isnt training based on MSE:[image]

When I try to fit this model:

```
print('tf version', tf.version.VERSION)

train_size = int(len(oral_ds) * 0.67)
print(train_size)
test_size = len(oral_ds) - train_size
print(test_size)
train = oral_ds[:train_size]
test = oral_ds[80319:119881]

print(len(train), len(test))

X_train = train.drop(columns=['PRICE','WEEK_END_DATE','Optimized rev','Original rev'])
y_train = train.PRICE

X_test = test.drop(columns=['PRICE','WEEK_END_DATE','Optimized rev','Original rev'])
y_test = test.PRICE

print('xtrain',np.shape(X_train))
print('xtest',np.shape(X_test))
print('ytrain',np.shape(y_train))
print('ytest',np.shape(y_test))


X_train=X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1)
#y_train=y_train.values.reshape(y_train.shape[0],y_train.shape[1],1)
X_test=X_test.values.reshape(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1)
#y_test=y_test.values.reshape(y_test.shape[0],y_test.shape[1],1)

#print('reshaped xtrain',np.shape(X_train))
#print('reshaped xtest',np.shape(X_test))
#print('reshaped ytrain',np.shape(y_train))
#print('reshaped ytest',np.shape(y_test))


single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4,
                                            input_shape=(37,1)))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))
single_step_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')



BATCH_SIZE=32
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))

history = single_step_model.fit(train_data, epochs=3)
single_step_model.summary()
```

I have tried to implement solutions from other posts such as:

- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39334/recurrent-neural-network-lstm-dimensions-error
- [ValueError: Input 0 of layer cu_dnnlstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 175]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361829/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-cu-dnnlstm-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected)

But neither of these are working.

Anyway any guidance?

Comment: Follow this link for your problem. Clearly explained here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416792/12598386

Comment: Thank you Tamang, I have tried this and it doesn't seem to be working. I have updated my code to show the same error message

Answer (score 0):

So in general LSTM expects 3 dimensonal inputs:

```
 (#batch_size, #number_of_features, #timesteps)
```

for which the feature and timesteps indices change depending on the platform. I guess you have 37 timesteps and 1 feature, so just change your input to:

```
 (#batch_size,37,1) or (#batch_size,1,37)
```

So see the following dummy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([100, 37, 1])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units =50 ,input_shape=(37,1))
output = lstm(inputs)
>>print(output.shape)
(100, 50)
```

The code in the following works end-to-end:

```
X_train = np.random.rand(80319,37,1)
y_train = np.random.randint(0,1,80319)
BATCH_SIZE=32
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = train_data.cache().shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    
single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4,
                                            input_shape=(37,1)))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))

single_step_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
single_step_model.fit(train_data, epochs=10)
```

and if you remove the batch size selection it throws the exactly same error.

Comment: Thank you Berkay, I have tried this, but I still get an error message. To be clear I have tried:
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1000, 1,37))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1000, 37,1))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1,37))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (37,1))


```ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1000, 1, 37]

```

Comment: Pleasee add your model summary and tensorflow version

Comment: tf version = 2.2, model summary updated in question. Thank you Berkay!

Comment: For  the first two you don't need to specify batchsize ( I assume 1000 is your batch size).  For the last two it should work actually, if you are wrangling your input correctly.

Comment: Im still getting the same error message. Is it correct Im not supposed to reshape the y data? I am also not sure what you mean with wrangling. Do you mean I am not splitting data correctly?

Comment: Its working! The mistake was with in using these two lines: ```train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))``` I removed those and just used ```regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)```

Comment: @AnnejetLouise I have added a fully working example and showed what is the problem

Comment: You will want to train it with batches so adapt my answer instead of that approach

Comment: @AnnejetLouise please close the question by selecting the answer

Comment: Sorry @berkay, but the model still is not running properly. I have updated the code above. For some reason it is not calculating the mse loss and therefore the model is not improving or learning.

Comment: I mean ask another question instead of changing the question